# Do Firewall and Domain Controller need to in same network for authentication?

Tags: active-directory, firewall, authentication, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

My company has a firewall. My company don't have any Domain Controller nor Windows Server device.

My boss plans to configure the firewall to let users authenticate with their corporate credential (AD) before accessing company resources. He want to build a Windows server(probably latest version OS) which act as domain controller (DC). The firewall will authenticate against the DC via Kerberos/LDAP/RADIUS protocol. My boss plans to host the server with cloud service provider.

The DC will not place in my company. Can I configure the firewall with the IP address of the DC? Does both device need to be in the same network in order to work? If no, do I need a VPN connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work, but just plan it correctly. You can usually configure a VPN tunnel to the cloud provider to access the DC. Thus the server will be in another IP scope, but accessible from your local LAN.

The computer will have to have the DC in their DNS entrys and the VPN tunnel to be open.

Comment: If I don't want to use VPN(means they are not on the sam network), can I just configure the firewall with the DC's public IP address or URL?

Comment: @ChongO.K. no. It's a firewall to firewall VPN, (site to site vpn) it will be transparent to everyone. you can't put your only dc on a dmz.. if it's your intention.

Comment: I know its not safe and not advisable to make DC open to public because it will cause security concerns.I just want to know that whether its technically possible if I configure the firewall(inside my company) to authenticate (Kerberos/LDAP/RADIUS) with the DC's(hosted in cloud provider) public IP address or URL without using VPN?

Comment: Yes, please see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for all ports, and open necessary port